# App won't close (Glass, Unity3d)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-glass

I have an Android Studio project, generated from a Unity3d Project.

I wanted to run my project on a Google Glass so I followed this tutorial (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-build-for-google-glass.219558/).

Everything works fine so far, but I can't close the app via swipe down, even though I added this to the UnityPlayerActivity.java:

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){ finish(); }
    return true;
}
```

Again, everything else works just fine.

## 1st UPDATE:

I tried the application on a tablet - like on the Glass, "Back"-button does not work.

Then I implemented this in Unity:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
    Application.Quit();
}
```

Now it works on the tablet, but the Glass-situation did not change.

### 2nd UPDATE:

This also didn't work: `this.finishAffinity();`

### 3rd UPDATE:

I tried to close my Unity Application using this Coroutine in the `Start()`-Method:

```
IEnumerator waitAndExit(int sec)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
    Application.Quit();
}
```

This successfully shuts down my application, so the problem appears to be this:

**Unity does not recognize swiping down on Google Glass as a keyEvent in `Input`** and **the `UnityPlayer` object seems to get ALL input from android**.

How can I stop that?
I wan't to handle touchpad events with java, but my original idea - overriding `onKeyDown` - did not work.

### 4th Update:

I tried to recognize a gesture like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092614/back-swipe-not-working-in-google-glass-activity) and added this to my `onCreate()`:

```
mUnityPlayer.setFocusable(false);
//mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
```

Unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Did you debug to see whether the method is called with the parameters you expect? If `finish()` is called, what does it do?

Comment: log your code and check what happen there or if it really gets there. Are you sure that swipe gesture calls "KEYCODE_BACK"?

Comment: @Thomas I am 100% sure `finish()` works, as I tested it seperately and `Toast.makeText(...).show()` also won't work.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla According to the GDK docs, yes! And I also tried to detect a gesture (s. my 4th Update of the question). It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution, but rather a work-around:

Using [contextual voice commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#unlisted_commands) works fine, even with the `UnityPlayer`-object blocking touchpad input.

I now close my app via *"OK glass - quit"*.

If anybody figures out how to solve it properly - I'll test, verify and accept your answer.